# Formatting a double to String using DecimalFormat is throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android

I have an Android application in the market which uses this snippet of code to convert a string to double. The string has validations to check if it is a real decimal value. This is running fine in most cases but throwing an exception occasionally. I am pretty sure this is localization issue and this is being caused on devices not using the US English.

[In most of the cases I know that value=0.]

Here is my code. The code in if else block throws the exception.

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale("en", "en"));
symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##", symbols);
double temperature = Double.valueOf(numberString);
if (tempUnits.equals("f")) {
    mBBTValue.setText(df.format(temperature) + " °F");
} else {
    mBBTValue.setText(df.format(getTemperatureInCelcius(temperature) + " °C"));
}
```

This code is throwing the following exception in some countries.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.text.NumberFormat.format(NumberFormat.java:304)
at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:702)
at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
at com.mysa.DetailsActivity$InitTask.onPostExecute(DayDataDetailsActivity.java:543)
at com.mysa.DetailsActivity$InitTask.onPostExecute(DayDataDetailsActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong in this code.

Comment: What does `getTemperatureInCelcius` return? It feels like you should be able to provide a short but complete example of this which *just* does formatting, without any of the rest of the code around fetching the temperature etc.

Comment: In my opinion, don't use `DecimalFormat`; instead use `String.format()`.

Comment: Thank you guys for trying to help. the issue was with the ordering of my brackets as mentioned in the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call

```
mBBTValue.setText(df.format(getTemperatureInCelcius(temperature)) + " °C");
```

instead of

```
mBBTValue.setText(df.format(getTemperatureInCelcius(temperature) + " °C"));
```

Note the different positions of the closing brackets. Your current version appends the `" °C"` before it formats it rather than formatting the number and then appending the `" °C"`.

Comment: Oh, that was such a silly mistake from me. Thank you for the catch. Need to move to write unit tests :).

Answer (score 3):

```
 // DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##", symbols); causing problem
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

> To obtain a NumberFormat for a specific locale, including the default
> locale, call one of NumberFormat's factory methods, such as
> getInstance(). In general, do not call the DecimalFormat constructors
> directly, since the NumberFormat factory methods may return subclasses
> other than DecimalFormat. If you need to customize the format object,
> do something like this:
>
> ```
> NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(loc);  if (f instanceof
> DecimalFormat) {
> ((DecimalFormat) f).setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);  }
> ```
>
> A DecimalFormat comprises a pattern and a set of symbols. The pattern
> may be set directly using applyPattern(), or indirectly using the API
> methods